# Having trouble with add crystal report path

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, crystal-reports

I am trying to add crystal report file name in my program, but it's doesn't work.
i used load(server.mappath(""));// but it doesn't support(no intellisense), may be i am missing some namespace.

i added following namespaces.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;  
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
```

Instead of that if i hard-code the path like "C:\\abc.rpt" then it works fine, but i need a permanent solution for this.
even "~\\abc.rpt" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution.

System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

i used windows form that's why server.mappath didn't work.